How to Add Visual Studio 2022 to DevOps 2019 build pipeline options
Trying to add Visual Studio 2022 to the option list for a visual studio build task in a build pipeline. So far this is not working. We want to build projects using .NET Framework 4.8.1 using build pipelines.

We installed Visual Studio 2022 on the build server (2016 server runs
multiple build agents)
Agents have been restarted and are the latest version available from
clicking "update all agents" in the agent pools settings - 2.153.1
after restarting the agents the option for visual studio 2022  did not appear in the task in the visual studio build task dropdown.
DevOps server version: Dev17.M153.3
when running the build in question, the visual studio build task fails with the error that .net framework 4.8.1 is not supported or available and the log says it is using Visual Studio 2019 for the task (Latest version is selected)

I see that there is a way to manually download a newer agent version from github, but I'm not sure this is the best path.  Is there a way to install that into DevOps so that future agents will also be the latest version?

May I know what you mean by server runs multiple build agents? Are there multiple agents in one self-hosted agent pool? Have you installed VS2022 on all the agents in that pool and restarted the agent service on each machine? Can you see the capability of VisualStudio_17.0 for each machine? If possible, please provide more details with some screenshots and error messages when running your pipeline to help narrow down the cause of the issue. Thx a lot.

we have a build server and there are about 7 agents installed on that server along with several versions of visual studio. the agents are all in the default agent pool.  There are other agents installed on other servers but these ones in the default pool are the ones we use for build pipelines. None of the agents show VisualStudio_17.0 as a capability.

Do you mean you configured 7 agents under different paths on the same server machine? Have you restarted those agent services on this machine after the installation of VS 2022 to rescan capabilities? And if possible, can you download the agent zip package, extract it to another path and configure a new agent to check its capabilities? If the VS 2022 was installed correctly before configuring the new agent, the capability should be visible.

That is correct, there are 7 agents each installed to a different path on the machine. I did remove and reinstall one of them. They are all reporting the same version number.  Other agents I installed on a Windows Server 2022 machine also have the same version number.  Is it possible we need to update devops to a newer version in order to enable this capability?

Hi @Matt, Have you got a chance to test the workaround suggested by Kevin to upgrade your VS build task for your ADO Server 2019? Hope it may help resolve your query in this post. Thx for the sharing.

Based on your description, you are using the Azure DevOps Server 2019(version: Dev17.M153.3).

the log says it is using Visual Studio 2019 for the task (Latest version is selected)

The default Visual Studio Build task version: 1.151.2. The root cause of the issue is that this task version doesn't support VS2022.
In this case, even if you upgrade the Agent version and read vs17.0 in the agent capacity, it still cannot be used in the VS build task.
To solve this issue, you need to upgrade the VSBuild task to a higher version(e.g.  1.192.3)
Here are the steps:
Step1: Download VSBuildV1.zip (version 1.192.3) and unzip package to the machine where the Azure DevOps Server located.
Step2: Install Node.js and tfx-cli. Command: npm install -g tfx-cli
Step3: Run command below to update the VS Build task version:
tfx build tasks upload -u {CollectionURL} -t {PAT} --task-path {PATH_TO_UPDATED_TASK}

After doing the steps, you will see the vs2022 shows in the dropdown list.
For example:

When you run the Pipeline, it will use the VS2022 in VS Build task.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this ticket: MSBuild@1 task is not updated to support VS2022

Would it be preferable to update the devops server to a later version? The agents themselves do not show the capability to handle visual studio 2022.

@Matt Yes. it should be a good choice to upgrade the server to latest version. In this case, these issues will be fixed in newer version server.

If you need to keep using devops server 2019, you can use the steps in my answer to solve the vsbuild issue. And you can download the newer version of the agent in github(e.g. 2.195.0 or higher) to solve the agent capability issue(we can refer to this agent release not: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases/tag/v2.195.0) , it shows the bugfix: Update PowerShellCapabilitiesProvider to work with Visual Studio 2022.

Not at this time, thank you for your answer, I will mark when I have a chance to try implementing the solution.

Thanks for your feedback. We will wait for your update.

went with the cloud version of devops and this seems to work for the time being.


Trying to add Visual Studio 2022 to the option list for a visual studio build task in a build pipeline. So far this is not working. We want to build projects using .NET Framework 4.8.1 using build pipelines.

After installing the Visual Studio Build Tools remember to restart the build agents to refresh the environment variables that might have been created or updated.
You can then select the version of Visual Studio when using the Visual Studio build task.
When using the classical pipelines, select the version from the Visual Studio Version dropdown:

When using the YAML pipelines set the vsVersion property:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    vsVersion: '17.0'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

Allowed values are:

latest (default)
17.0 (Visual Studio 2022)
16.0 (Visual Studio 2019)
15.0 (Visual Studio 2017)
14.0 (Visual Studio 2015)
12.0 (Visual Studio 2013)
11.0 (Visual Studio 2012)

Please note that if the preferred version cannot be found (e.g. it's not installed), the latest version found will be used instead.

this did not work.  I specified that we restarted the agents in the original question.

@Matt yes I know you specifed it, but I feel that it's something that should be mentioned in the answer.

@Matt what exactly do you mean by "this did not work"? Any error messages? ...

I mean after I installed visual studio on the server and restarted the agents and also updated them from within the devops agent pool, the visual studio 2022 option did not appear in the dropdown in the visual studio build task in the build pipeline.  Other than the build failing I don't know what I would even look for as far as error messages, everything seems to be running.
